# How do I check if a file exists in a remote?

Tags: git, git-remote

Is there a way to check if a file under specified, relative path exist in a remote? I'm fine with fetching the info first if it's the only option. In other words I'm looking for git-ls-files with an option to specify remote and branch. I'm only interested if the file exists (a list of files on the branch will do as well), I don't care about hashes, diffs etc.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use

```
git cat-file -e <remote>:<filename>
```

which will exit with zero when the file exists. Instead of `<remote>` above you'd use a remote branch name (but it could in fact be any tree-ish object reference). To use such a remote branch, you'll need to have the remote repository configured and fetched (i.e. by using `git remote add` + `git fetch`).

A concrete example:

```
$ git cat-file -e origin/master:README && echo README exists
README exists

$ git cat-file -e origin/master:FAILME
fatal: Not a valid object name origin/master:FAILME
```

**Two things to note:**

- Use `/` as path delimiter in filenames, even on e.g. Windows.
- `<filename>` is a full path (such as `foo/bar/README`), relative to the root of the repository.

Comment: By `<remote>` you mean a remote branch, which means you have to have configured the remote and run `git fetch <remote>` first; you're examining the remote branch in your repo, so you need to make sure that's up to date.

Comment: Hello @earl thanks for answer, but I cant get why it's not working correctly in this case.
I've successfully removed `.idea/` folder from remote repository, but not locally with code
`git rm --cached -rf .idea`
Then I've tried to see if it sill on the remote repository with code
`git cat-file -e origin/branch:./.idea`
and it returned with 0 which means `.idea/` is still on remote repository ?

Answer (score 11):

You can use [*git archive*](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html) to access individual files without downloading any other part of a repository:

```
if git archive --format=tar \
               --remote=<remote_name-or-URL> master README >/dev/null; then
  echo 'master has README'
else
  echo 'master does not have README (or other error)'
fi
```

The archive service (`upload-archive`) may not be enabled on all servers or repositories though, you will have to test it for the servers and repositories that you need to access.

If the archive service is not available, you will have to fetch objects through normal means.

If you do not already have a remote setup for the repository in question you can do a “shallow” fetch into FETCH_HEAD (this needs to be done in a Git repository, but it can be completely unrelated or even empty):

```
git fetch --depth=1 remote_name-or-URL master
if git rev-parse --verify --quiet FETCH_HEAD:README >/dev/null; then
  echo "repository's master has README"
else
  echo "repository's master does not have README"
fi
```

If you have a remote defined for the repository, then you probably just want to update it and access the file through the normal remote-tracking branches:

```
git fetch remote_name
if git rev-parse --verify --quiet remote_name/master:README >/dev/null; then
  echo "remote's master has README"
else
  echo "remote's master does not have README"
fi
```

Comment: be warned: the `git-archive` solution not work reliably. it seems to check only for existence of the top level files / directories, e.g.: `git archive --remote=<repo> master dir-that-exists/then/some/nonsense/path` would exit with 0