# Sparse checkout for a specific file on empty repo

Tags: git, git-checkout, sparse-checkout

I have two repos: ci-test and ci-test2. The ci-test repo contains a CI.yaml file and the ci-test2 repo is empty. Using mgit, I am performing a sparse checkout of only the CI.yaml file on both repos and I get the error, "Sparse checkout leaves no entry on working directory". I am almost sure that this happens because I am trying to checkout the file in the ci-test2 repo which does not contain it. I was wondering if there is a way to gracefully handle this error, perhaps by looking into git read-tree. This is just an example, I have many more repos than this and my mgit checkout class does not know anything about the contents of my repos. Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even before the sparse checkout itself, you could check if the remote repository has the `CI.yaml` file: see "[How do I check if a file exists in a remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4135049/6309)".

But if you already have fetched the repository (and only need to checkout/[restore](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) one file in it), a [`git cat-file -e`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cat-file#Documentation/git-cat-file.txt--e) could work:

> ```
> -e
> ```
>
> Exit with zero status if `<object>` exists and is a valid object.
> If `<object>` is of an invalid format, exit with non-zero and emits an error on stderr.

Comment: Hi, VonC. Thanks for your answer! Say, I only need to checkout/restore files, can I checkout more than one perhaps a list of files?

Comment: @StefMan Sure: the `git restore` command (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) can take multiple files as parameters. `git restore file1 file2 ...`

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the help!