# How to check with git if a file is committed but not pushed

Tags: git

With `git status --porcelain <file>` I can check if a file
is modified, deleted, added, ...

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status#_short_format

If the file was modified and committed locally, `git status --porcelain <file>` doesn't return any value.

With `git status <file>`, I get that the whole repo is x commits ahead, but that's for the whole repo and not for a single file only.

How can I check a single file if it's committed but not pushed.

Comment: You can see if commits have been pushed, but not files. Or you can check if a file exists _at all_ in the remote. See [How do I check if a file exists in a remote?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135049/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-in-a-remote)

Comment: The `git push` command pushes commits, not files. Of course, each commit *contains* files, so you might not care about the distinction—but Git cares, so it makes you care too. :-)

Answer (score 3):

A pretty close thing I can think of :

```
git fetch

# check if there are modifications on said file in your current branch
# versus its "fork point" from its upstream branch
#  - '@{u}' is short for "the upstream of the current branch"
#  - 'git diff a...b' (3 dots) is short for "the diff between b and
#    the  fork point between a and b"

git diff --name-only @{u}...HEAD -- path/to/file
```

If no output is printed, this means that all the modifications you have on that file *in your current commit* have been uploaded to the upstream.
If there are *other* differences in the upstream branch, this means they come from some other source (someone else pushed changes to that branch, or a pull request was merged, or ...)

You still have to use `git status path/to/file` or `git diff HEAD -- path/to/file` if you want to see whether there are uncommitted modifications on that file.

---

use `--quiet` to use it as a condition in a script :

```
if ! git diff --quiet @{u}...HEAD -- path/to/file; then
    echo "there are some differences in path/to/file"
fi
```

Comment: Just use `--quiet`, `git diff --quiet @{u}...@ that.file || echo changed and committed locally

Comment: @jthill: nice addition, updated my answer. thanks !

Comment: `git status` runs core commands internally, to check for changed and added, you can use `git diff-index --quiet @ that.file` and `git diff-files --quiet` for their effects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `git diff --cached` and the `git status --verbose` as well.

The `git diff` command displays the changes between the working directory and the staging area.

The `git status` command is run to show the state of the working directory and the staging area.

The `--verbose` option not only shows the names of changed files but also displays the textual changes staged to be committed.

Answer (score 0):

When you commonly push something toward a repository, you usually work on a branch configured to "track" an homologous one located in the remote repository. The state of this branch is maintained locally each time you fetch the branch, either using `fetch`, `push', 'pull` or when you do `git remote update`.

So what you simply need to do once you have committed is to compare you local branch and its remote counterpart. This will tell you if a commit has been pushed or not yet, then you can specify a file name to restrict the comparison to this sole file.

Assuming you're working on *master*, this will tell you if there are discrepancies in general:

```
git diff origin/master master [your_file]
```

And this one will tell you which commits are not pushed yet:

```
git log origin/master..master [your_file]
```

Here, `origin/master` is the remote branch ans is on the left because it's supposed to represent the original state, `master` is the local branch and immediately follows the former one because it's supposed to be the state we're reaching.

Comment: @LeGEC : Indeed! Thanks for this precision, I just fixed it.